# Possible for Spring to rollback for everything except log4j error logging to db?

Tags: hibernate, spring, exception, log4j

I am having issue with this, as i get into some exception, and i will called log4j to log the error. But all of them are rolled back. Any idea? or any alternative ways to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your log database and transactional database are the same?  That's not a pattern I'd recommend.

Sounds like the log4j logging is using the same data source and transaction as your business logic.  Try setting up a separate data source for the log4j database appender - that way it can't participate in any transaction for the rest of the system.